# WordPress Error Establishing Connection on Temporary URL with Vesta VPS

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, vps

I have a VPS(VestaCP) with a WordPress installation, and the domain is no longer available. I have set up a temporary URL Using the following instructions: [Link](https://vestacp.com/docs/#how-to-configure-temporary-links-for-new-domains)

I now have an issue establishing connection.

I've went into the wp-config.php and added the following lines thinking it would solve my issue... But it didn't

```
// Add these lines to wp-config.php:
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://*tempurlhere*-com.alpha.*myurl*.com/');
define('WP_HOME',    'http://*tempurlhere*-com.alpha.*myurl*.com/');
```

Is there something I'm missing? Should I replace the url with the server IP?

Comment: What issue are you having? What is the error?

Comment: @SashaPachev I'm just getting an "ERROR ESTABLISHING DATABASE CONNECTION"

Answer (score 1):

The reason for "ERROR ESTABLISHING DATABASE CONNECTION" is the inability of WordPress to reach MySQL or authenticate properly. Check the values of `DB_USER`,`DB_HOST`,`DB_PASSWORD`, and `DB_NAME`. Fix if needed. Make sure the user exists in MySQL, is allowed to connect from your web host, and has the rights to the database given by `DB_NAME`. If that does not solve the problem, check if MySQL server up and running. If yes, can it be reached from the web server (e.g. maybe MySQL port is firewalled)?

To check accessibility of the MySQL server from your web host, `ssh` to the web host, and run:

```
mysql -u <DB_USER> -p<DB_PASSWORD> -h <DB_HOST> <DB_NAME>
```

Replacing `<var>` with the actual values. Note the absence of space between `-p` and the DB_PASSWORD value.

If the connectivity is confirmed, double-check that you are editing the correct `wp-config.php` that WordPress is actually using, e.g by adding `die("Loading this file now");` at the very top of it, then check if you see that message when you load the site.

If that is indeed the case, verify that the PHP installation includes a functional MySQL driver by writing an small program that will use `mysqli_connect()` with the relevant credentials and report success or error.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer. I've actually made sure all of the following were valid before posting the question.

I'm starting to believe the issue is somewhere in the URL since it is temporary.

Comment: Do you have ssh on the web host?

Comment: Yes, I do .. that's how I've access wp-config  and installed WP

Comment: I was able to get in doing that. Using localhost as the DBHOST @SashaPachev